# How can I derive Seller's Payout status

Tags: paypal

This get account status api
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/partner-referrals/v1/#merchant-integration_status
has the flag-**payments_receivable** to check if seller can receieve payments from Buyers
but what about capability to get payouts from the paypal. where can that be checked?

Is there a way to calculate this information?

Answer (score 0):

If payments are receivable, that means payouts are receivable.

If you want to know whether a seller account can send payouts, the most you can do is (using that referrals API) request permission for the `MASS_PAYMENT` product which is equivalent to Payouts. I have no idea what this will do when the account is not eligible to send Payouts; the vast majority of accounts are not enabled for the feature.